# deploy seperate api and ui with NOW | nodejs

Tags: node.js, vercel

I'm not sure if what I want is possible, I haven't found anything that says it could be done.
Mostly I "think" it should be possible.

The thing is: I have a seperate file for my api and user interface, and would love to deploy both using zeit-now for now (see file struct below, hope it's clear).

Now the main question is, is it possible to deploy both api.js and server.js using zeit-now?

Kind regards,
Daneel

```
root
|-api
|--api.js
|-ui
|--server.js
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless you specify your own [custom routes](https://zeit.co/docs/configuration/#routes) in your `now.json` file, anything in the root `api` folder will be treated by Zeit as both serverless functions and the core of your project. Your best bet is to deploy two separate projects within Zeit — your frontend (which should be a static-build JAMstack-style site) and your backend, which is comprised of serverless functions, to which your frontend app makes API calls.